# Getting error while saving PairRdd in Spark Stream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to save my Pair Rdd in spark streaming but getting error while saving at last step .

Here is my sample code

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val inputPath = args(0)
    val output = args(1)
    val noOfHashPartitioner = args(2).toInt

    println("IN Streaming ")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val hadoopConf = sc.hadoopConfiguration;
    //hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")

    val ssc = new org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))
    val input = ssc.textFileStream(inputPath)

    val pairedRDD = input.map(row => {
      val split = row.split("\\|")
      val fileName = split(0)
      val fileContent = split(1)
      (fileName, fileContent)
    })
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
    import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat

    class RddMultiTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
      override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = NullWritable.get()
      override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = key.asInstanceOf[String]
    }
    //print(pairedRDD)

    pairedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(noOfHashPartitioner)).saveAsHadoopFile(output, classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RddMultiTextOutputFormat], classOf[GzipCodec])

    ssc.start() // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination() // Wait for the computation to terminate
  }
```

I am getting at last step while saving .I am new to spark streaming so must be missing something here .
Getting error like

> value partitionBy is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(String, String)]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

`pairedRDD` is of type `DStream[(String, String)]` not `RDD[(String,String)]`. The method `partitionBy` is not available on `DStream`s.

Maybe look into `foreachRDD` which should be available on `DStream`s.

EDIT: A bit more context explanation `textFileStream` will set up a directory watch on the specified path and whenever there are new files will stream the content. so that's where the stream aspect comes from. Is that what you want? or do you just want to read the content of the directory "as is" once? Then there's `readTextFiles` which will return a non-stream container.

Comment: I just have to save this pairedRDD back ..

Comment: it is a possibly infinite stream. the notion of saving it is different. `DStream` are discretized stream with constituent RDDs (but again, possibly infinite many) so you can safe each RDD but you can't save the entire stream.